# Again looping issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I just wrote a simple bunch of code, which had to remove duplicates in list, but there was an issue.
Can somebody explain me why it is skipping number 3 ?

```
lis = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 1, 1, 3, 6, 6, 6, 1, 4, 7, 6, 5]
for i in lis:
    while lis.count(i) > 1:
        print(f'removing {i} ... ')
        lis.remove(i)
        print(lis.count(i))
print(lis)
```

Comment: Do not modify (`remove`) a list while iterating over it (`for`). Python should really throw an error instead of providing unpredictable/unexpected/surprising results. Other programming languages (e.g. C#) simply don't allow this.

Comment: I need to understand logic,
I assume, when we remove the ones, number 3 becomes our first element, than loop takes second element which is already 4, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes, but please don't rely on that to be the same in future versions. Use `result = list(set(lis))` instead (or other solutions for removing duplicates, like constructing a new list)

Comment: Note: Now that `dict` is insertion-ordered, removing duplicates while maintaining order is both super-efficient and trivial to code: In-place version `lis[:] = dict.fromkeys(lis)` (involves the temporary `dict`, but modifies the contents of the original `list`, so aliases see the changes), new `list` version `list(dict.fromkeys(lis))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take your list, convert it to a set and then back to a list:

```
listofthings = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 1, 1, 3, 6, 6, 6, 1, 4, 7, 6, 5]

newlist=list(set(listofthings))

print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use list.remove() if u dont want to remove all 3s or all 1s

```
listofthings = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 1, 1, 3, 6, 6, 6, 1, 4, 7, 6, 5]


for things in listofthings:
    exists = 1
    obj = things
    cnt = 0
    for things in listofthings:
       cnt = cnt + 1
       dup = things
       if dup == obj:
          exists = exists + 1 
       if exists == 2:
           del listofthings[cnt]
```